# sort and remove duplicate based on different columns in a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file in which there are three columns as (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 12-digit number) :

```
2016-11-30 23:40:45.578 5001234567890
2016-11-30 23:40:45.568 5001234567890
2016-11-30 23:40:45.578 5001234567890
2016-11-30 23:40:45.478 5001234567891
2016-11-30 23:40:45.578 5001234567891
```

I want to first sort the file based on the date-time(first two columns) and then have to remove the rows having duplicate numbers (third column).
 So after this the above file will look like:

```
2016-11-30 23:40:45.478 5001234567891
2016-11-30 23:40:45.568 5001234567890
```

I have used sort with key and `awk` command(as below) but the results aren't correct..(I am not very sure which entries are being removed as the file that I am processing are too big.)
Commands:

```
sort -k1 inputFile > sortedInputFile<br/>
awk '!seen[$3]++' sortedInputFile > outputFile<br/>
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the earliest instance of each 3rd column entry, you can sort twice; the first time to group duplicates and the second time to restore the sort by time, after duplicates are removed. (The following assumes a default sort works with both dates and values and that all lines have three columns with consistent whitespace.)

```
sort -k3 -k1,2 inputFile | uniq -f2 | sort > sortedFile
```

The `-f2` option to `uniq` tells it to start the comparison at the end of the second field, so that the date fields are not considered.

Comment: I tried the command but it didn't remove all the duplicates. After the above command I used awk command and it worked. What could be the reason for that ?

Comment: @k.thanvi: perhaps there is trailing garbage (or even whitespace) in some lines. The `uniq` command compares lines byte by byte after skipping the fields, whereas the awk program only compares the third field. Try hexdumping (with `hd`) two duplicate lines which were not eliminated.

Comment: @K.Thanvi: Now that I think about it, it is also possible that the whitespace between the second and third field differs, because `uniq -f2` starts comparing after the end of the second field, and not at the beginning of the third field -- that is, it includes the whitespace between the second and third fields. So if one line has a single space and another line has the same third field but with two spaces before it, `uniq` will consider those different lines.

Answer (score 1):

If milliseconds doesn't matter, following is another approach which removes the milliseconds and performs the `sort` and `uniq`:

`awk '{print $1" "substr($2,1,index($2,".")-1)" "$3 }' file1.txt | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in awk. It groups on the `$3` and stores the earliest timestamp but the output order is random, so the output should be piped to `sort`.

```
$ awk '
    (a[$3] == "" || a[$3] > ($1 OFS $2)) && a[$3]=($1 OFS $2) { next } 
    END{ for(i in a) print a[i], i }
' file # | sort goes here
2016-11-30 23:40:45.568 5001234567890
2016-11-30 23:40:45.478 5001234567891
```